# CPU temperature too high but fan not running at max speed

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

My processor fan never runs on full speed event though my processor temperature is going so high. I am using HWMonitor (also speedfan) to record temperatures and my temperature readings in normal are as follows:

```
Intel Core 2 Quad Q2800:
Core # 0: 65 c
Core # 1: 60 c
Core # 2: 59 c
Core # 3: 59 c
```

But during high usage like while playing a game or something it hits around 80+, I tried cleaning the grill and fan and putting new thermal grease but it didn’t help.

HWMonitor further says:

```
FANS PWM: 
FANSWMIN0: 50%
```

And from the above reading I am guessing that my fan is running on 50% always and I think it is because it looks slow... Not really making any sound and you can feel any air blowing out of it if you put your hand in front of it.

I tried SpeedFan but my motherboard isn’t supported… My BIOS also doesn’t have any such option all it has is:

```
Advanced > Fan Control
- Processor Zone Response - Normal
- Processor Zone Damping – High
- Auto Fan Detection – Disable
- Fan Detection Error- Enable
```

My specs are as follows:

```
Motherboard: Intel DG43NB [Version AAE34877-402]
CPU:  Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz [Socket 775 LGA]
```

I want to know how to take my CPU temperature to normal again (probably by making my fan run to max speed)?

---

Just checked processor specification here: [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/products/36547/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8200-(4M-Cache-2_33-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB))
And it says for Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q8200:

```
TCASE 71.4°C
```

I am not sure about the usage of TCASE.

Comment: That's not really THAAAAT hot...

Comment: Thats the minimum temperature ive mentioned.. as i said above during high times like playing a game or something it climbs upto 80+ ~90 C..

Comment: does hwmonitor display the rpm for your fan?

Comment: I missed the part where it gets over 90, that's a worry.  Can you specify WHAT the fan is (or at minimum, is it voltage modulated or PWM)?  Also what the motherboard is and where and how the fan is connected?

Comment: @ Victor T.: no it doesnt.. But speedfan does and it is saying that Fan1: 30240 rpm, Fan2: 30240 rpm, Fan3: 23160 rpm,Fan4: 1920 rpm

However m confused as why it is showing 4 fans as in real only have one cpu fan and at max one more fan in power supply thats it!

Comment: @Shinrai : Ive Motherboard: Intel DG43NB [Version AAE34877-402]
fan is connected to the socket in motherboard
Am not sure how to find _or at minimum, is it voltage modulated or PWM_ .. can you please specify?

Comment: What socket in the motherboard, specifically (how is it labeled, most boards have multiple fan headers).  What model is the fan?  If you can't figure either of those out, *how many pins is the fan connector*?

Comment: @Shinrai: it is connected here [see pic](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/502/inteldg43nbfanconnector.jpg/)
and acc. to the label over it, it is: _Foxconn FN832691 (DC 12V - 0.14A)_

Comment: I can't seem to find that fan model number.  Is the connector three pins or four?  If it's three, there's probably a setting in the BIOS for fan controller mode you need to change - unfortunately I am very unfamiliar with Intel motherboards, so I wouldn't know what to look for (and I don't have time to investigate right now ;_;).  Alternatively, get a fan header to MOLEX adapter and run it off your power supply.

Comment: its four pin connector.

Comment: Then maybe the thermal control on this motherboard is just terrible. :/

Comment: Have you verified your on the latest BIOS version? I've seen many BIOS's that report the wrong temp which causes the fan to either be on more or less than it should be. Looks like if your pre 0098 you could have issues. Can you verify you are on 0107?

Answer (score 5):

`Control Panel -> Power Options -> Edit Plan Settings -> Change Advanced Power Settings -> Processor Power Management -> System cooling policy -> Active`

This is about the only system controlled method to control the fan speed / processor load mannerisms.

Alternatively, for more control, you would have to update your BIOS as suggested by @ZianChoy and attempt to control fan speed using SpeedFan.

You should also be able to control Fan Speed via the BIOS even prior to updating it, some BIOS interfaces let you configure rules, fixed RPM, or `Modes` whereby you could select `High Performance` making your PC slightly louder but effectively cooler.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your BIOS as RemyService suggests.

You could also try putting swapping the CPU, fan, or motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I've experiencend the same and my fan didn't run at full speed even when I max out cpu usage so I've written a windows driver to control the fan. I suggest to download the RW tool and check the embedded controller for the temperature and speed value. I'm not an expert but it's usually the ec talking to the fan and cpu. Maybe you can get more insight when you disassemble the DSDT from the BIOS-ROM. In my laptop the ec value 0x94 controls the fan mode and the value 0x95 sets the speed. Another value is to monitor the cpu temperature and you can watch it with RW. To read and write to the ec and write a program you need to write either a driver or you need a special library like winring0. A windows driver needs to be signed by an authority for a small fee.

Comment: What is RW tool, and ec? Thank you!

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer:https://rweverything.com/

Comment: "$ dmesg|grep DSDT
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x0000000079FE9000 00E963 (v01 HPQOEM INSYDE   00000000 INTL 00040000)
[    0.360783] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions
[    0.430499] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions and events" Do you know what that means? Thank you.

Comment: If you are confused on why I am asking all these questions, see this: https://superuser.com/questions/1247263/what-are-the-different-reasons-for-laptops-new-fan-to-run-too-too-slow

Comment: I used the rw everything tool. The DSDT thing didn't work for me!