# What are the different reasons for laptop's new-fan to run too too slow?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling

Let me narrow the case, consider my laptop HP Pavillion G6 2230TX. Fan runs too too slow (I can know it to be running only after placing ears near it), that it seems as if it is not running. It has stayed calm even when temperature was 80 degree C. Fan was replaced in the last week, after cleaning all the dust. Here is how the motherboard with fan looks:

[image: IMG_20170730_124439]

What are the reasons for laptop fan to run too too slow, other than dust?

Comment: Answer can be found her
https://superuser.com/questions/353703/cpu-temperature-too-high-but-fan-not-running-at-max-speed?rq=1

Comment: For those in Linux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT